# Changing date format for PostgreSQL query result

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have following query

```
select substring(listDate from '............$') as v_end_date,
substring(listDate from '^...............') as v_start_date
```

Now listDate value can be like

```
select substring('06 Jan 2014 to 12 Jan 2014,
 13 Jan 2014 to 19 Jan 2014,
 20 Jan 2014 to 26 Jan 2014
' from '............$') as v_end_date,
substring('06 Jan 2014 to 12 Jan 2014,
 13 Jan 2014 to 19 Jan 2014,
 20 Jan 2014 to 26 Jan 2014
' from '^............') as v_start_date
```

Above query results in

```
V_END_DATE  V_START_DATE
26 Jan 2014 06 Jan 2014
```

Now I need to have `v_end_date` and `v_start_date` format like `yyyy-mm-dd` and like 
`Mon 06 Jan 2014`.

Answer (score 5):

Convert your string to an actual [`date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) with [`to_date()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) and use [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) to get pretty much *any* format you like.

Demo:

```
SELECT to_char(day, 'YYYY-MM-DD')     AS format1
     , to_char(day, 'Dy DD Mon YYYY') AS format2 
FROM   (SELECT to_date('26 Jan 2014', 'DD Mon YYYY') AS day) sub
```

Comment: Recommended. Never store dates in string format, you can not calculate dates and times with that.